# Is there any risk of being hacked if I install an AMP stack?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I need an AMP stack on Ubuntu (Apache + Php, Mysql and Phpmyadmin) but i'm scared that I can get hacked, I would use it just for learning propose, I will NOT connect it to the Internet, I don't want it to be connected to the Internet  because I don't like the idea that a remote user could access to my stuff.

Does the "stack" automatically connects to the Internet or I should give it the permission?

Is there anyway to stop Apache and mysql from starting in the boot?

PD: I just want to be able to access through my computer, not sharing it on the Internet

Comment: I appreciate your help but I'm still curious, how can I avoid exposing it to the Internet? sorry for my childish questions but in kinda paranoid about this stuff

Comment: I think the thing you are missing is NAT and Firewalling. Installing these services allows remote users to issue commands to the services on your box, and sometimes these commands may allow them to take inappropriate access. The key here is that the attacker is calling out to you, not the other way around. By using a firewall with NAT will block people from the Internet from accessing your services, but allow local users to use them. Most of the time the firewall is integrated into a router. If you do not have a router, then you should not install these services.

Comment: And Frank, it only will be used by me and only in my local machine,  I have no plans to share it on a net

Comment: do an online port scan and check that the ports are not open. http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/port-scan/   And be aware of what port the server(s) are running ,  make sure the port scan is testing those ports.   You  could also do a port scan from another machine on your network. And you could do a test locally to see what ports are open (netstat -aon),  e.g. your apache one would be if testing locally, and just test for those ports to see they're not open from an  online location i.e. do an online port scan on just those ports.

Comment: You can run a command that gives you a comma separated list of all your ports e.g. in windows cmd,  something liek  `C:\blah>netstat -aon -p tcp | grep "LISTENING" | grep -o ":[^: ]*" | grep -P ":[0-9]+$"  | grep -v "^:0$"  | uniq | tr -d '\r' | tr -d '\n' | sed "s/:/,/g" | cut -b 2- >list`  Once you have that list then you can put it at that online port scanning link.